# Draw 3D rectangle, that does something different for each of its side you click on

Tags: c#, wpf

A client with a container shipping business wants me to create a WPF windows app. After a physical examination of a container, his employees will click on a 3d rectangle (which represents the physical metal container), to mark which side of it came in damaged. I will insert that information on an SQL table.

Now I have no problem with the SQL side of things but I am a super noob when it comes to WPF and I don't know how to draw a 3d rectangle like one in the picture attached where each of its sides call a different method when you click on it. any ideas or help is welcomed.

[image: 1]

Comment: To learn how draw a shape you could take a look at [this MS Doc Page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/graphics-multimedia/shapes-and-basic-drawing-in-wpf-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8). But detecting where user has clicked on it is completely different topic, it would probably involve handling Canvas.MouseLeftButtonDown event.

Comment: Why did you also tag this question `WinForms`? Quite unrelated, in relation to what you're asking. Remove if out of context, otherwise clarify.

Comment: i just thought that winforms and wpf are cousins but yeah i should delete it

Comment: There are *similarities* in some departments, but in relation to graphics, not really much in common (you can also read *totally unrelated* when it comes to 3D rendering).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the "rectangle" does not rotates, it should be simple enough to just use [polygons](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/graphics-multimedia/how-to-draw-a-closed-shape-by-using-the-polygon-element?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) to draw each side. This has a MouseDown event, to it should be fairly easy to just attach event handlers to the polygons for each side.

If you need to rotate the box you have a few options, but you probably need some basic knowledge about 3D graphics to use this effectivly. One is to create your own rotation matrix to rotate a 3D box, but do the drawing with 2D polygons. Another option would be to use [wpf 3d](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/graphics-multimedia/3-d-graphics-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) classes to do the drawing, see also [How to: Hit Test in a Viewport3D](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/graphics-multimedia/how-to-hit-test-in-a-viewport3d?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8).

Comment: hey thank you very much! i will check every bit of info you posted thankfully it does not need to be in 3d